# Spring Boot, Java 9 and Maven multi-modules project can't find sibling module + Lombok generated methods

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, lombok, java-platform-module-system

I try to migrate a Spring Boot project which I began to develop without modules, to a Java 9 Jigsaw architecture.

I can't figure why (I tried many solutions and passed a few hours on this problem) but when building my *service* module, which depends on my *common* modules, classes of *common* aren't reachable.

Note: all my `module-info.java` files are under the `src/main/java` folder in each module.

Thank you in advance, I don't know what's wrong with my configuration...

Here is what I get when I try to do a `mvn clean install` ine the project's root folder:

```
[INFO] 54 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  2.449 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.242 s]
[INFO] service ............................................ FAILURE [  3.058 s]
[INFO] api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.602 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-25T18:40:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[3,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[13,103] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class LovedTrackDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[3,48] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[4,48] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[19,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTrackDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.common.LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Pair
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.ConverterFactory
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/LastfmService.java:[3,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/LastfmService.java:[4,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/LastfmService.java:[31,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTracksDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.LastfmService
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/LastfmService.java:[37,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TagDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.LastfmService
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter.java:[3,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter.java:[15,117] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ImageDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter.java:[21,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ImageDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.common.LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[3,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[4,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[19,139] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class LovedTracksDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[25,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTracksDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[47,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTrackDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/toptags/LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter.java:[3,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/toptags/LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter.java:[17,142] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class TagDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/toptags/LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter.java:[24,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TagDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.toptags.LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter.java:[3,55] package com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter.java:[10,93] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class TagDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter.java:[17,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TagDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.common.LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[20,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LovedTrackDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.common.LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[21,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getMbid()
[ERROR]   location: variable t of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiTrackDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[22,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getArtist()
[ERROR]   location: variable t of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiTrackDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[22,64] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getName()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiArtistDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[23,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getName()
[ERROR]   location: variable t of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiTrackDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[24,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getDate()
[ERROR]   location: variable t of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiTrackDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTrackDto_to_LovedTrackDto_Converter.java:[25,51] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getImage()
[ERROR]   location: variable t of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiTrackDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[30,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable ClassUtil
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.ConverterFactory
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[45,70] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Pair
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.ConverterFactory
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[62,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable ClassUtil
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.ConverterFactory
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/ConverterFactory.java:[68,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Pair
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.ConverterFactory
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter.java:[25,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable ImageDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.common.LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter.java:[26,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getText()
[ERROR]   location: variable i of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiImageDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiImageDtoList_to_ImageDtoList_Converter.java:[27,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getSize()
[ERROR]   location: variable i of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiImageDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[26,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTracksDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[26,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTracksDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[34,22] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getLovedtracks()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiUserGetLovedTracksResponseDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[35,22] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getAttr()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[36,22] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getTotal()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksAttributesDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[42,22] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getLovedtracks()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiUserGetLovedTracksResponseDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[43,22] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getTrack()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.user.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/lovedtracks/LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter.java:[50,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class LovedTrackDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.lovedtracks.LastfmApiLovedTracksResponseDto_to_LovedTracksDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/toptags/LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter.java:[25,108] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getToptags()
[ERROR]   location: variable lastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.track.toptags.LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/toptags/LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter.java:[26,22] invalid method reference
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]     symbol:   method getTag()
[ERROR]     location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiTopTagsDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/toptags/LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter.java:[29,48] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TagDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.toptags.LastfmApiTrackGetTopTagsResponseDto_to_TagDtoList_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter.java:[19,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable TagDto
[ERROR]   location: class com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.converter.lastfm.common.LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter.java:[20,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getName()
[ERROR]   location: variable lastfmApiTagDto of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiTagDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiTagDto_to_TagDto_Converter.java:[21,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getUrl()
[ERROR]   location: variable lastfmApiTagDto of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiTagDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiDateDto_to_Date_Converter.java:[32,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getText()
[ERROR]   location: variable date of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiDateDto
[ERROR] /D:/lastfm-playlists-workspace/lastfm-playlists-server/service/src/main/java/com/lastfm/playlists/server/service/api/converter/lastfm/common/LastfmApiDateDto_to_Date_Converter.java:[34,69] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getText()
[ERROR]   location: variable date of type com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.model.common.LastfmApiDateDto
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :service
```

Here's my main `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>common</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.21</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-edge</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.lastfm.playlists.server.api.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My `common` module `pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>common</name>
</project>
```

The associated `module-info.java`:

```
module common {
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires jackson.annotations;
    requires lombok;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.data.mongodb;
    requires java.validation;
    requires spring.core;
    exports com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.utils;
    exports com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model;
    exports com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm;
}
```

My `service` module `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>service</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The associated `module-info.java`:

```
module com.lastfm.playlists.server.service {
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.web;
    requires lombok;
    requires jackson.annotations;
    requires common;
    exports com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api;
    exports com.lastfm.playlists.server.service.api.lastfm.exception;
}
```

And my `api` module `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>api</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lastfm.playlists.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The associated `module-info.java`:

```
module api {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires java.validation;
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires common;
    requires service;
    requires spring.data.mongodb;
}
```

Comment: The first things which comes into my mind is: LovedTrackDto is that class contained in a package which has a appropriate exports in module-info file? Furthermore I don't understand why are you trying to define module-info in a spring boot app cause all the jars will be packaged into a single executable jar which would violate the module-info by default cause you can haven only a single module-info file ...

Comment: Hello, in fact `LovedTrackDto` is under the package `com.lastfm.playlists.server.common.model.lastfm` in the `common` module which effectively exports this package. I think I did it correctly here. For Spring Boot, I found some examples on the Internet that seem to work, so I think there is a way to do it but I don't know where I fail in it...